# Ratio of volume to radius of a sphere

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, volume

If I have two spheres of a known volume $V$ and radius $r$ and I make one bigger sphere out of them, what will the new sphere's radius be?

For example:
Sphere $1$: $r_1=2$, $V_1=8$.
 Sphere $2$: $r_2=2$, $V_2=8$.
 New sphere: $r_n=?$, $V_n=16$.

Edit:

I need to use it in programming. The units are the same for all measurments and don't matter to me. I found out that the ratio is 1:8 but I don't know how to apply this. How does it work the other way if I divide the sphere in half? What if the spheres are different volume?

My work:
$r_n$=$r_1$+1/8$r_2$
Then
$v_n$ ≠ $v_1$+$v_2$

Code:
*if(p1.r>p2.r)

{

    p1.r=p2.r/8 + p1.r;

}

else

{

    p1.r=p1.r/8 + p2.r;

}*

For anyone interested visual help:
http://dharman.eu/planets/index.html

Comment: What did you attempt so far?

Comment: Could you please help address a question of @JonathanY. ? Are the $x$, $y$ and $z$ directions measures in the same units?

Comment: @JonathanY. Edited  question

Comment: **Which** ratio is 1:8?

Comment: Volume to radius, If the volume doubles the radius is increased by 1/8r(btw my calculations are wrong thats why i need your help)

Comment: "If the volume doubles the radius is increased by"... by what exactly? Sorry but at the moment you are not making any sense.

Comment: When two spheres of the same volume collide new sphere's radius is $r_1$ + 1/8$r_2$. But when the New sphere's volume is calculated again it's more than it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sphere with radius $r$ will have volume $V=(4/3)\pi r^3$. Evidently you're using different units for volume and radius, but it turns out that it doesn't matter for this problem, so we'll say that $V=kr^3$. Suppose you have two spheres with radii $r_1, r_2$. Their combined volumes will be
$$
k(r_1)^3+k(r_2)^3 = k((r_1)^3+(r_2)^3)
$$
If they are combined to make a big sphere with radius $R$ we'll have
$$
k((r_1)^3+(r_2)^3) = kR^3
$$
and so we'll have
$$
R^3 = (r_1)^3+(r_2)^3
$$
and so, taking third roots,
$$
R=((r_1)^3+(r_2)^3)^{1/3}
$$
In your example, with $r_1=r_2=2$, you'd have the radius of the new sphere 
$$
R=(2\cdot 2^3)^{1/3}=2^{1/3}\cdot 2\approx 2.5198
$$

Comment: This answer is right, thank you. I added this formula to my code and the calculations are correct now.